# Proj Oblique Mercator two-point method very useful?

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, oblique-mercator

I am happy with Proj oblique Mercator Azimuth (+alpha) method,
but I am also itching to try the two points method. But just like
@ralph-tee showed in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/337169/77230 ,
the origin is stuck to the equator:

```
echo 0 0|proj -I +proj=omerc +lonc=-87 +lat_0=42 +alpha=0
87dW    42dN
echo 0 0|proj -I +proj=omerc +lon_1=-87 +lat_1=42 +lon_2=-87 +lat_2=43
87dW    0dN
```

What parameter might I adjust to make the second answer the same
as the first? Or should I give up on the two-point method?

Update: I'm submitting https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/4039
which should put the nail in the coffin for the idea that Proj's two-point method is useful.

Comment: With this case? Use +x_0 and +y_0. Projection -87 42 forward in the two-point case, then use the negative of those values for the false easting/northing parameters. Might work even with true oblique case, but you might have to use the +no_rot parameter.

Comment: Thanks @mkennedy but it is time they fixed the documents. I have now submitted https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/4039 so users know not to bother trying Proj's two-point method.

Comment: Incorporated comment (and another comment I started to write) into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Disclosure: I work for Esri.

It's a valid method. Esri calls it a natural origin case (natural origin=where the central line crosses the equator). The two point natural origin case is described first in John P. Snyder's [Map Projections: A Working Manual](https://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf) (PDF) on book page 69 for the sphere.

Esri has a variant called 'center' too. So under [Hotine oblique Mercator](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/properties/hotine-oblique-mercator.htm), 4 variants based on how it's constructed and then where the 0,0 point is located.

1. azimuth using center
2. azimuth using natural origin
3. two point using center (identified as longitude midway between the 2 defining
   locations)
4. two point using natural origin two point with center/natural origin

There's also RSO (rectifying skew orthomorphic which supports both alpha (azimuth) and gamma (rectifying angle applied at the end).

Given what's available in PROJ, you can use +x_0 and +y_0. Project -87 42 forward in the two-point case, then use the negative of the output values for the false easting/northing parameters. Might work even with a true oblique case, but you might have to use the +no_rot parameter.

Comment: Well, OK. But this is quickly getting over my head. At least I am
hopefully getting the Proj project to stop documenting their two methods
as working the same.